# Can I merge new and existing data in a D3 join?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to maintain a list of elements indexed by a key, that acts like an accumulator on that key.

I have a real-time update cycle which repeatedly generates a subset of items indexed on the same key, and I want to animate the accumulation process as they are absorbed into the existing list.

In my simple example, I just want to count the number of times I've seen each key.

If I had all the data to start with, I'd just use `d3.nest()`, but I don't want to reaggregate the entire history or redraw every item every time I get an update.

I'd like to use D3 to join my new data items into the existing selection, and merge the old and new data for each key, but I can't see how to avoid my new data items just overwriting any existing data.  Is there a way to combine the existing datum with the new datum to produce a merged datum?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head
    <body>
        <div id="stuff">
        </div>

<script>

// set up a list of accumulators with count set to 0
d3.select('#stuff')
  .selectAll('.grid')
  .data(
    d3.range(10).map(function(i) { return {key: i*2, count: 0}; }),
    function(d) { return d.key; }
  )
 .enter().append('div')
  .classed('grid', true)
  .text(function(d) { return 'key: ' + d.key + ', count: ' + d.count });

// while(true) receive new items...

// now repeatedly receive a new list of items to accumulate into the existing list
var ticks = [{key: 4}, {key: 8}, {key: 14}];

// how can I combine the old and new datums during this join?
d3.selectAll('.grid')
    .data(
        ticks, 
        function(d) { return d.key; } 
        /*  Conceptually want to provide a function to merge old and new datum */
        //  , function(dnew, dold) { dold.count += 1; return dold; }
   )
  .text(function(d) { return 'key: ' + d.key + ', count: ' + d.count });

</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Above outputs:

```
key: 0, count: 0
key: 2, count: 0
key: 4, count: undefined  <== would like '1'
key: 6, count: 0
key: 8, count: undefined  <== would like '1'
key: 10, count: 0
key: 12, count: 0
key: 14, count: undefined  <== would like '1'
key: 16, count: 0
key: 18, count: 0
```

My non-D3-ish way to do it is to pull out the matching data elements, merge, and then reinsert, like so:

```
...

var tickmap = d3.map();
ticks.forEach(function(d){ tickmap.set(d.key, 1); });

var sel = d3.selectAll('.grid'),
    merged = sel.data()
        .filter(function(d) { return tickmap.has(d.key); })
        .map(function(d) { d.count += tickmap.get(d.key); return d; });

sel.data(merged, function(d) { return d.key; })
  .text(function(d) { return 'key: ' + d.key + ', count: ' + d.count });
```

Comment: You need to read this whole section of the D3 wiki: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter

Comment: That's not a very productive comment. I don't want to enter new elements, I want to update the data in existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a d3.map() to do a manual in-place merge via the filter function, which seems a bit more D3-ish.  This doesn't deal with new items, but in my case I know the base grid ahead of time, I just don't know which points I want to update each time step.

```
... 

var tickmap = d3.map();
ticks.forEach(function(d){ tickmap.set(d.key, 1); });

d3.selectAll('.grid')
  .filter(function(d) {  // filter and update only matching items
    if (tickmap.has(d.key)) {
      d.count += tickmap.get(d.key);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })
  .style('color', 'red')  // redraw matching items in red
  .text(function(d) { return 'key: ' + d.key + ', count: ' + d.count });

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of an idiomatic D3 way of handling this, but accomplishing what you wish should be as easy as augmenting your ticks data by comparing to the selection data before binding, i.e.:

```
ticks.forEach(function(t) {
    var boundData = d3.selectAll('.grid').data().filter(function(d) { return d.key === t.key; });
    t.count = boundData[0] ? boundData[0].count += 1 : 0;
});
```

Note that this also accounts for potential new elements

See: http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/852/

Comment: Yes, that's similar to the extract/filter/update solution I must have been adding at the same time as you wrote.  Though your forEach approach requires scanning the entire grid for each new element.